# Intel hd or Mobility Radeon?

Tags: graphics-card, intel-graphics, dell-studio, ati-mobility-radeon

I have decided to get a new Dell Studio 15 laptop. They have an option of adding a "ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 4570, 512MB" card for an extra $100 instead of the included "Intel HD Graphics" card.

How do the two compare? The laptop comes with an Intel Core i3 processor, maybe the Intel graphics card would be more compatible with the processor since they're made by the same manufacturer?

Comment: I would go with ATI, because, like @Chris said, the ATI will be better for higher-end stuff, and will have better graphics. In the end, it boils down to what you want to do with your Studio 15 laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need the laptop for some 'light' office tasks, then the Intel GMA will do (don't fall for the "HD Graphics", this card is by no means multimedia powerhouse). If you want to watch HD movies or play games, then cough up the $100 extra, it's well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

If this notebook follows the usual patterns then the Intel will be a host-based video system (shares CPU and RAM with system) and the ATI Mobility will have its own processors and RAM.  So you'll get (more than likely, haven't actually tested it myself ;) ) better video performance out of the ATI option.

Keep in mind that the ATI option will probably drain the battery faster.

Not sure this is really a 'serverfault' question though... Probably better off at [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

The Intel HD integrated graphics card i3 or i5 is more than capable of displaying games like world of warcraft or something else, on low/medium that is.

Intel GMA en Intel Integrated HD graphics are 2 separte products and divisions at Intel
Intel GMA is a chip on the motherboard, HD graphics is an integrated solution in the CPU itself (not the same die though)

The Intel HD Graphics can display HD like a charm, also it does dts and dolby hd audio tru HDMI 1.3 something integrated graphics adapters like the ATI one you mentioned cant.

:)

Comment: I'm sorry but  for the HD Audio, the Mobility Radeon 5xxx series do it pretty well, so to say that Intel GMA HD will be better on this, is totally wrong.

Comment: If the HD graphics is integrated in the CPU itself, does it degrade the performance of the CPU by sharing resources?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do any kind of gaming, you'll want the ATI adapter.

Comment: Is the intel hd incapable of playing some of the new games out there?

Comment: @Absolute0 - Certainly incapable of playing games that require 3D acceleration.

Comment: @Molly7244: Why do you say that?  "Intel® HD Graphics delivers high-quality, high-definition (HD) video playback, advanced 3D capabilities, and full support for the Microsoft Windows 7* operating system, without the need for a discrete graphics card."

Comment: @endolith That's just marketing speak, frankly.  Any kind of significant 3D gaming is going to be much more enjoyable with a discrete graphics array.

Answer (score 0):

ATI and nVidia graphics chipsets run circles around Intel Chipsets in every measure except cost. The Intel chipset will be cheaper because it doesn't run high end graphics (or not very well at all). If you run gaming, CAD, or other graphics intensive applications then spring for the ATI chip; for most business type needs the Intel chip will preform fine.